# Cut a sequence of length N into subsequences such that the sum of each subarray is less than M and the cut minimizes the sum of max of each part

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence, sub-array

Given an integer array sequence `a_n` of length `N`, cut the sequence into several parts such that every one of which is a consequtive subsequence of the original sequence.

Every part must satisfy the following:

1. The sum of each part is not greater than a given integer `M`
2. Find a cut that minimizes the sum of the maximum integer of each part

For example:

```
input : n = 8, m = 17 arr = [2, 2, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 1]
output = 12
explanation: subarrays = [2, 2, 2], [8, 1, 8], [2, 1]
sum = 2 + 8 + 2 = 12

0 <= N <= 100000
each integer is between 0 and 1000000
```

If no such cut exists, return -1

I believe this is a dynamic programming question, but I am not sure how to approach this.

I am relatively new to coding, and came across this question in an interview which I could not do. I would like to know how to solve it for future reference.

Heres what I tried:

```
n = 8
m = 17
arr = [2, 2, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 1]

biggest_sum, i = 0, 0
while (i < len(arr)):
    seq_sum = 0
    biggest_in_seq = -1
    while (seq_sum <= m and i < len(arr)):
        if (seq_sum + arr[i] <= m ):
            seq_sum += arr[i]
            if (arr[i] > biggest_in_seq):
                biggest_in_seq = arr[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            break
    biggest_sum += biggest_in_seq
if (biggest_sum == 0):
    print(-1)    
else:
    print(biggest_sum)
```

This givens the result `16`, and the subsequences are: `[[2, 2, 2, 8, 1], [8, 2, 1]]`

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me... wouldn't the "minimum" a subarray could have just be a single element subarray? So from your example `arr` -> `[[2], [2], [2], [8], [1], [8], [2], [1]]`?

Comment: @Sharhad you still need to ask a specific question (see [ask]). You were unable to solve this question, but your attempt is still useful because it helps you come up with that specific question. When you just paste the question here without showing any of your effort, it looks like you're trying to get us to help you cheat on your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are filling every sequence from left to right up to the maximum allowed value `m`. You should evaluate different options of sequence lengths and minimize the result, which in the example means that the 2 `8` values must be in the same sequence.

a possible solution could be:

```py
n = 8
m = 17
arr = [2, 2, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 1]

def find_solution(arr, m, n):
    if max(arr)>m:
        return -1

    optimal_seq_length = [0] * n
    optimal_max_sum = [0] * n

    for seq_start in reversed(range(n)):
        seq_len = 0
        seq_sum = 0
        seq_max = 0
        while True:
            seq_len += 1
            seq_end = seq_start + seq_len
            if seq_end > n:
                break
            last_value_in_seq = arr[seq_end - 1]
            seq_sum += last_value_in_seq
            if seq_sum > m:
                break
            seq_max = max(seq_max, last_value_in_seq)
            max_sum_from_next_seq_on = 0 if seq_end >= n else optimal_max_sum[seq_end]
            max_sum = max_sum_from_next_seq_on + seq_max
            if seq_len == 1 or max_sum < optimal_max_sum[seq_start]:
                optimal_max_sum[seq_start] = max_sum
                optimal_seq_length[seq_start] = seq_len

    # create solution list of lists
    solution = []
    seg_start = 0
    while seg_start < n:
        seg_length = optimal_seq_length[seg_start]
        solution.append(arr[seg_start:seg_start+seg_length])
        seg_start += seg_length

    return solution

print(find_solution(arr, m, n))
# [[2, 2, 2], [8, 1, 8], [2, 1]]
```

Key aspects of my proposal:

- start from a small array (only last element), and make the problem array grow to the front:

  - `[1]`
  - `[2, 1]`
  - `[8, 2, 1]`
  - etc.
- for **each of above problem arrays**, store:

  - the optimal **sum of the maximum** of each sequence (`optimal_max_sum`), which is the value to be minimized
  - the sequence length of the **first** sequence (`optimal_seq_length`) to achieve this optimal value
- do this by: for **each allowed sequence length** starting at the beginning of the problem array:

  - calculate the new `max_sum` value and add it to previously calculated `optimal_max_sum` for the part after this sequence
  - keep the smallest `max_sum`, store it in `optimal_max_sum` and the associated seq_length in `optimal_seq_length`